# Why is my thumbnail from video using AVAssetImageGenerator is not showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm generating thumbnail from video. But in this data show error Here is my code below:

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageFromURL:(NSURL *)videoURL {
AVAsset* asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
generate.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
generate.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
NSError *error;
CMTime time = asset.duration;
CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:nil error:&error];
UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
return thumb;
```

}

And this code show error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11832 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media cannot be used., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000001e8d20 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12431 "(null)"}}
```

Anyone know reason why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to specify an `actualTime`.

Comment: Can' you explain details for me?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong... haven't looked at Obj-C in awhile. It might be the `time` that you're inputting which you set to be the duration (ie, you've set it to the very end). Maybe try the beginning (ie 0).

Comment: And I am making the assumption that it is a valid url.